# Unusual exception behaviour?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, .net-4.0, access-violation

I have never come across this kind of behaviour before and I wondered if anyone is able to shed some light on the matter?

So as you can see in the picture, I am catching exceptions of type `AccessViolationException`, and yet the debugger is complaining that the exception is unhandled!

How is it possible?

[image]

Oh, and I know you shouldnt have an empty `catch` block, that's not my question.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Now I am getting this one instead:

[image]

Comment: One shot in the dark: wrap the whole foreach with additional try-catch

Comment: BTW, what happens if you run the code (as opposed to debugging it)?

Comment: Hi, I tried doing a release build and I can still reproduce the problem, except obviously I don't have the ability to debug it - but it crashes under the same conditions as before.

Comment: @max: Placing the try block outside the foreach is definitely something you want to do for performance reasons, jumping in and out of exception handling can be a real pain.

Comment: What are you sending the keys to? Can you somehow look inside the  SendWait stack?

Comment: The keys are sent to the active window. The crash happens when the active window is Firefox and I try to load a page with lots of content - or any action which causes the browser to stutter for a moment.

Comment: When it can't send keys to the active window this exception will occur. Either handle it and make sure the keys are resend when the active windows gives your control back, or build in the ability to sleep when a page is being loaded. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I guess there are better ways than sending unstable keys...

Comment: Yes, there are probably better ways. I'm not trying to achieve anything actually, but I did want to know where the error was coming from since it was something new to me.

Answer (score 3):

[Handling Corrupted State Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) is something you have to do explicitly, you can catch those by adding the `[HandledProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute to the function...

Please note that these are unhandled with a reason as unexpected conditions can still be harmful if they are ignored or dealt with generically. There is no guarantee in either of these scenarios that what you're doing is completely safe! Only handle it in a scenario  where just terminating the process is unacceptable.

Comment: Are you saying that I may run the risk of damaging other data on my machine?

Comment: It doesn't allow you to access the memory, so in the case of this exception the change is very low that other data on your machine would be damaged. So I guess you could try to use the attribute and catch it, or figure out why it's giving that exception just for sending those keys...

Comment: Hi, I have added the attribute as suggested and inverted the `foreach` and `try`-`catch` blocks. Now I'm getting a new problem (see my update).

Comment: I see, can you reflect my last comment on your question too?

Comment: Perhaps you can catch that exception, but given the text that might be a risky thing to do...

Comment: Thats the wierd thing - its not an exception

Comment: Ah, it was late... Scroll down on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Odd things like this happen to me once in a while, I'm going to recommend the newbie IT method. Restart your computer. The CLI Environment in .NET gets really buggy sometimes as I've had my code literally hang inside of a foreach loop before.

Comment: Then you would either have memory corruption or you're writing something bad, as this isn't normal behavior and .NET isn't that buggy. Restarting his computer might result in the same fault if some code is causing this exception... Writing thread-unsafe code, adjusting the thing you are enumerating or processing a lot can cause the foreach loop to hang too; none of these would be considered a bug in the CLI environment.